# Chrome transition is drawing ghost lines

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have some content hidden in a drawer on my site. When you open the drawer, a CSS transition is used to pull it down.

This works fine for me on all platforms - Chrome, Firefox and IE on Windows - but a colleague has encountered an issue with Chrome on OSX, whereby the transition appears to be drawing lines all the way down, on the far sides.

Here's an example page: http://nonaynever.net?preview_theme=Minimal2014

And here's a screenshot of the problem: http://cl.ly/WvCE

CSS

```
#dock {
   margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
   height: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}
```

I'm only a hobby coder, so might be missing something obvious I've got wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug caused by the `opacity: 0;` on `#dock` and triggered with the `transition`. Is the `opacity` needed?

This is a bug fix:

CSS

```
#dock {
   margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
   height: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   /* opacity: 0; */
   transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}
```

---

**OR**

If you do want to keep the opacity transition where possible, as this appears to be a webkit only bug:

Cancel out the opacity for webkit browsers only with `-webkit-opacity: 1;`.

CSS

```
#dock {
   margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
   height: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-opacity: 1; 
   transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to work. The opacity was non-essential, so I've removed it. We just did a little dance - thanks!!

Comment: Awesome! Also try `-webkit-opacity: 1;` after `opacity: 0;`. That way you can cancel it out for Chrome where it has issues but leave it for other browsers.