# CSS: Transition Left Bug

Tags: css, css-transitions

I found some strange bug in Chrome when I am using `-webkit-transition-left`. After hovering over the link there are some traces from a blue thing left behind. Here is an image of what I am talking about. 
[image]

What I want is, as you see, the the ABOUT US is sitting outside from the circle and when I hover over I wanted it to go in. In Firefox it is perfect but in Chrome it is messed up.

Any ideas how to fix it or if there is a better solution?

```
-webkit-transition: left 500ms;
-moz-transition: left 500ms;
-ms-transition: left 500ms;
-o-transition: left 500ms;
```

Comment: share a fiddle and please don't use offensive words.

Comment: Often transitions show artifacts due how actually your machine is rendering on screen (and they wont show on other machines). It could be possible that this might your case, however it could also be something else. It will help if you share a demo.

Comment: Does the `opacity` change with this transition? There is a chrome bug that appears when a CSS transition changes the opacity. If so, [here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159068/chrome-transition-is-drawing-ghost-lines/25159511#25159511) where I posted an answer.